# How can you use an Apex class from the hello.apex script

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

How can you use an Apex class from the hello.apex script in a newly created standard project with VS Code?

This is probably really simple, I thought I should use some 'using' or 'include' statement but I cannot find the information. This is what I did:

I am working from VS Code.
sfdx create project.
chosen: Standard.
In the directory scripts/apex I open the file hello.apex.
Log in to org, vscodeOrg.
sfdx Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor contents, this succeeds.
sfdx Create Apex Class, called NewClass with static function
right under the constructor I add a static method, the complete class code is now:

```
public with sharing class NewClass {
    public NewClass() {
    }
    public static void Test() {
        System.debug('call from apex class');
    }
}
```

The file is located in: ...\NewStandardProject\force-app\main\default\classes\NewClass.cls

Go back to hello.apex, execute still succeeds.

I add in the hello.apex file:

NewClass.Test();

Making the script code this:

```
string tempvar = 'Enter_your_name_here';
System.debug('Hello World!');
System.debug('My name is ' + tempvar);

NewClass.Test();
```

The editor gives me 'Intelligent code completion', so it seems my new class is known.

I try to execute again with 'Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor contents', it fails with this feed back:

Error: Variable does not exist: NewClass

If I replace the static call with e.g.

NewClass nc = new NewClass();

It gives the same error.

If I replace public with global in NewClass, that also does not help.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you actually deploy NewClass.cls ? right click and deploy (unless your vscode is configured to auto deploy on save). Maybe it exists locally (can be used to build code completion indexes and stuff) but not yet on the server?

Comment: No I did not deploy the class.. And: Yes, that did the trick! I come from a Java/C++/C# background where files are just on your local disk. I am very happy with your help!

Comment: There's no equivalent of JRE with apex, you need to deploy them to server to run them. You deploy them plaintext, SF compiles them (no messing around with JAR/WAR). There's "lwc" local development if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question then to make this complete:

- Install sfdx
- Install vs sfdx plug in
- Press <kbd>Ctrl-Shift P</kbd> to call the sfdx from vs code
- `sfdx create project` -> Standard

In the directory `scripts/apex`, open the file `hello.apex`

Log in to org, vscodeOrg (or if you have no standard org yet call  control shift p, sfdx create a default scratch org)

sfdx Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor contents, this succeeds

sfdx Create Apex Class, called NewClass with static function
right under the constructor I add a static method, the complete class code is now:

```
public with sharing class NewClass {
    public NewClass() {
    }
    public static void Test() {
        System.debug('call from apex class');
    }
}
```

In the left pain click on the file in the project directory and choose 'sfdx deploy source to org'.

(And that step as a developer customed to working with local executables, I forgot).

Add in the hello.apex file: NewClass.Test();

Making the code there:

```
// Use .apex files to store anonymous Apex.
// You can execute anonymous Apex in VS Code by selecting the
//     apex text and running the command:
//     SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Currently Selected Text
// You can also execute the entire file by running the command:
//     SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor Contents

string tempvar = 'Enter_your_name_here';
System.debug('Hello World!');
System.debug('My name is ' + tempvar);

NewClass.Test();
```

I try to execute again with 'Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor contents'.

In the output amongst a few other lines you should see: 'call from apex class'.